# Python Class as Class variable

Tags: python, class

I am creating two classes, one which needs to hold an instance of the other. However I can not figure out how to properly initialize this.

```
class Buttons:
def __init__(self, number, scene):
    self.DICT = {}
    self.number = number
    self.DICT[number] = scene

def add_btn(self, number, scene):
    self.DICT[number] = scene

class Switches:
enclosure_name = ""
gatewate_name = ""
enclosure_id = 0
switch_name = ""
switch_location = ""
switch_device_id = 0
switch_mac = 0
switch_termination = 0
switch_group = 0
Buttons buttons = Buttons()
```

I plan to create many switches, each switch has 2 to 6 buttons. Each button has a number and an action. How can I put a Buttons variable into the switches?

Comment: Do it in `Switches.__init__` with `self.buttons = Buttons()`, currently you are only initialising the `Buttons` class once no matter how many times you call `Switches`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of this is that each `Switch` will contain one `Buttons` object, which contains a dictionary that represents multiple buttons.

The `Switches` class is a representation of multiple switches:

Simply give each switch a buttons attribute:

```
class Switch:

    def __init__(self):
        self.switches = {}

    def add_switch(self, number, buttons):
        self.switches[number] = buttons
```

And when creating a switch pass in a `Buttons` object:

```
switches = Switches(b)
b = Buttons(2, "scene")
switches.add_switch(10, b)
```

And you can still access the underlying buttons of a switch. For example adding buttons to the 10th switch:

```
switch.switches[10].add_btn(...)
```

And if you want to be fancy you can implement a `__getitem__` so you can index `switch` directly. Inside `Switches`:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.switches[item]
```

With this method you can add buttons directly:

```
switch[10].add_btn(...)
```

Comment: I used this and the comment above to come up with an answer. I do not like python but am forced to use it, so I use it kind of like java. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)